# При использовании особого объекта TextWriter свойство OutputStream недоступно

Tags: c#, asp.net

Хочу загрузить pdf-файл на страницу.
Для загрузки создал в контроллере следующий метод

```
        public FileContentResult Read(int bookId)
        {
        Book book = context.Books.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == bookId);

        string path = Server.MapPath($"~/Content/Books/{book.GeneratedName}");//Путь к файлу
        string type = $"application/{GetType(book.GeneratedName)}";//Тип файла

        byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);//Получение файла в байтовом виде
        return new FileContentResult(fileContents, type);
        }
```

Код представления, который вызывает этот метод и генерирует содержимое

```
        <p>@{Html.RenderAction("Read",new { bookId = Model.Id });}</p>
```

Но, при обращении к этой странице генерируется исключение

```
System.Web.HttpException: При использовании особого объекта TextWriter свойство OutputStream недоступно.
```

Comment: А вы уверены насчёт RenderAction? У вас же файл.

Comment: Вот тут, кажется, та же проблема: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776880/276994

Comment: @VladD Исключение исходит из System.IO, с FileContentResult он никак не связан

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что не связан? А вы пробовали то, что описывается в том вопросе? Кто бросает исключение — не обязательно тот, кто виноват.

Comment: @VladD да, я несколько раз поэкспериментировав понял, что исключение исходит из классов System.IO.А  еще я понял, что с FileContentResult мне не удастся загрузить контент на часть страницы, он все равно перенаправляет на отдельную страницу